# Obtaining command line interface wallet given fresh source (bitcoin/litecoin/altcoins)

Tags: compilation, command-line-interface

I've read alot but cant find the answer. I am curious as to how to obtain the command line interface wallet for crypto coins given fresh source code. For example litecoin. I'm willing to bet the steps are the same for bitcoin and others?

Anyway what I've tried is.

`git clone https://github.com/litecoin-project/litecoin.git`

`cd litecoin`

`make -f makefile.unix USE_UPNP=`

I also (dont know why) tried:

`qmake "USE_UPNP=-"; make`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To obtain the litecoin-cli from the source tree you must clone/fork https://github.com/litecoin-project/litecoin/tree/exp-0.9.3-preview4.

The github reached via a search engine is out of date in this respect.

Also I learned that the rpc api code was simply copied in to a different binary (copied, it's still in litecoind - allcoind's)

So this means I can simple to things like

`litecoind getnewaddress`

Instead of

`litecoin-cli getnewaddress`

This applies to all coins.

Comment: Also, parameters for both binarys have changed. I was strugling my brain until i found that tree to get the old way binary. Thanks.